# Minimal and maximal problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications, differential

Cuboid with contlstant volume $V$
its base is a rectangle length $nX$, width $X$ 
The whole area of cuboid is $A$ and $A$ was minimal area
Prove with differentiation that 
$A^3n=54 V^2(1+n)^2$

Comment: Use TeX-based code. Is $n$ natural?

Comment: Yes, n is natural